# How do I convert a label file of a particular format of json to txt label files based on yolo?

Tags: python, json, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I received the image dataset in jpg and labels in JSON, and I have a problem trying to train with darknet yolov4.

Labels in JSON format are as follows.

```
"annotations": [
    {
        "image_id": 0,
        "file_name": "image_47010552850673.jpg",
        "objects": [
            {
                "object_id": 0,
                "class": "person",
                "position": [1480, 151, 1508, 169]
            },
            {
                "object_id": 1,
                "class": "car",
                "position": [792, 123, 843, 246]
            },
            {
                "object_id": 2,
                "class": "person",
                "position": [245, 667, 286, 695]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "image_id": 1,
        "file_name": "image_68475401035381.jpg",
        "objects": [
            {
                "object_id": 3,
                "class": "person",
                "position": [1090, 374, 1096, 389]
            },
            {
                "object_id": 4,
                "class": "car",
                "position": [1279, 620, 1346, 655]
            }
        ]
    }, ...
```

The position is in the following format.

`position = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] <- pixel values`

There are six classes in total, and the corresponding numbers for each label class are as follows.

car: 0, truck: 1, bus: 2, etc vehicle: 3, bike: 4, person: 5

Image sizes are 1920x1080

It has approximately 100,000 images and a capacity of 36GB.

All images are labeled in one JSON file, and the JSON file has a capacity of about 124 MB.

I want to convert the above JSON file to get text files in normalized yolo format.

Ex)

file_name: `image_name.txt`

contents:

`class_number normalized_center_x normalized_center_y normalized_width normalized_height`

In addition,

> normalized_centered_x = (xmin+xmax)÷2÷x_sizeof_image
>
> normalized_centered_y = (ymin+ymax)÷2÷y_sizeof_image
>
> normalized_width = (xmax-xmin)÷x_sizeof_image
>
> normalized_height = (ymax-ymin)÷y_sizeof_image

In my case,

> normalized_centered_x = (position[0]+position[2])÷2÷1920
>
> normalized_centered_y = (position[1]+position[3])÷2÷1080
>
> normalized_width = (position[2]-position[0])÷1920
>
> normalized_height = (position[3]-position[1])÷1080

The actual example of darknet yolov4 txt files list for the above json is as follows.

file name: `image_47010552850673.txt`

contents:

> 5 0.778125 0.148148148 0.014583333 0.016666667
>
> 0 0.42578125 0.170833333 0.0265625 0.113888889
>
> 5 0.13828125 0.630555556 0.021354167 0.025925926

file name: `image_68475401035381.txt`

contents:

> 5 0.569270833 0.353240741 0.003125 0.013888889
>
> 0 0.68359375 0.590277778 0.034895833 0.032407407

How do I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2):

I found myself answering the question I asked.

```
import json


classes = ["car", "truck", "bus", "etc vehicle", "bike", "person"]


# box form[x,y,w,h]
def convert(size, box):
    dw = 1. / size[0]
    dh = 1. / size[1]
    x = (box[0] + box[2]) * dw / 2
    y = (box[1] + box[3]) * dh / 2
    w = (box[2] - box[0]) * dw
    h = (box[3] - box[1]) * dh
    return (x, y, w, h)


def convert_annotation():
    with open('labels.json', 'r') as f:
        datas = json.load(f)
        data = datas["annotations"]
        width = 1920
        height = 1080
    for item1 in data:
        file_name = item1["file_name"]
        objects = item1["objects"]
        outfile = open('./darknet2/%s.txt' % (file_name[:-4]), 'a+')
        for item2 in objects:
            cls = item2["class"]
            cls_id = classes.index(cls)
            box = item2["position"]
            bb = convert((width, height), box)
            outfile.write(str(cls_id) + " " + " ".join([str(a) for a in bb]) + '\n')
        outfile.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert_annotation()
```

Comment: If you need to convert to and from other formats I made a small utility to do so: https://github.com/laclouis5/ObjectDetectionEval.

Comment: Is it converting and making a textfile for every image in the dataset?